# Connecting to SQL Server from Raspberry Pi results in Error 35 (during pre-login handshake)

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'd want to ask what may be the reason that I'm able to connect to `SQL Server` from `Windows` finely, but when I'm attempting to connect to the same server, using same connection string and `server being pingable` from `Raspbian @ Raspberry Pi`, then this error occurs:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

---

> ex.InnerException  {System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
>    ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
>    ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, Byte[] recvBuf, Int32 recvOffset, Int32 recvCount, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
>      at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, ArraySegment`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)

I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient`

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

.NET Core 3.1

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the TCP/IP protocol enabled for clients (SQL Server prototcols) ?

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes

Comment: Not sure if this will help but you might try [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I can confirm that the same error happens using Microsoft.Data.SqlCliente and DotNet Core 3.1 And none of the answears listed fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed (checked for updates) OpenSSL as `Leszek Mazur` suggested:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

and then in `sudo nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

I changed minimal version of TLS from 1.2:

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

to 1.0:

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the openssl.cnf setting needed for your environment. I would have expected TLSv1.2 to work as well as long as the db server supports it per [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server). What SQL Server version and OS are you using?

Comment: @DanGuzman Hi, I don't really remember what version of SQL Server it was. The OS was the latest Raspbian IIRC

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update OpenSSL version.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Comment: Weird `Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1d-0+deb10u2).
openssl set to manually installed.` I rebooted also